# Can I modify the font shape on-the-fly in my chapter headings if I have used sectsty to format?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sectsty

I am having problems formatting the text in my chapter headings. I used `sectsty` to modify all my headings to `\sffamily`, but I have some parts of the heading that should be in italics and I can't work out how to achieve this.

Here's an example. It seems to work fine if I comment out the three lines relating to `sectsty`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{sectsty}          % put section headings in sans-serif font
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\chapterfont{\LARGE\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I want some \textit{Text In Italic} in my heading}

Where has the \textit{italic text} gone from my title?


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\ensuremath`, but simply `$\mathbf{B}$`, which in turn shouldn't be sans serif if in the text it is serif: it is a *symbol* and so it's not modifiable. If you find it conflicting with the style for chapter titles, then change the style.

Comment: I just used that example because it was a general example of something I have a lot in my text, used for various other things. I **want** the maths B to be roman. It's the italic text I want fixed. I only included that to show that I knew it was possible for some things to override the default (though I appreciate the example is a little different. I will remove it, as it's obviously confusing.

Comment: The Computer Modern fonts don't have a “sans serif bold italic”, so LaTeX substitutes with the nearest font according to its rules: the font family is changed last, the shape first. You find ``Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined, using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead`` in your log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Latin Modern font by adding

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your preamble will display "Text In Italic" in sans-serif, bold, *and* italic, which I assume to be the desired result.

I couldn't explain it better than egreg in his comment:

> The Computer Modern fonts don't have a “sans serif bold italic”, so
>   LaTeX substitutes with the nearest font according to its rules: the
>   font family is changed last, the shape first. You find `Font shape
>   'OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined, using 'OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead` in your log
>   file.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Nice to have such a simple solution for once!